# Using PHP to automatically output filesize for multiple files in a static html table

Tags: php

A gigantic HTML table has been created, without knowing how to use MYSQL initially.

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="book"><a class="booklink"  href="../book1.pdf" >Book1</a></td>
        <td class="year">2007</td>
        <td class="pages">32p</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="book"><a class="booklink"  href="../book2.pdf" >Book2</a></td>
        <td class="year">2010</td>
        <td class="pages">12p</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="book"><a class="booklink"  href="../book3.pdf" >Book3</a></td>
        <td class="year">2013</td>
        <td class="pages">42p</td>
    </tr>
,,,,,and so on,,,,,,
```

Is it possible using PHP to output filesize in newly added table data for every listed file ?

If I convert it to MYSQL-based table, certain amount of manual jobs would still need to be done to retain the HTML and CSS layout.

I believe that the dom function would solve the problem but I just don't know how to do it, for I'm totally a programing idiot!

Please help!

Thank you.

Comment: Is the data now stored in a database?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the filesize function http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

```
<?php echo filesize("../book1.pdf"); ?> bytes
```

Assuming your php file looks something like the following

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . filesize($row["filename"]) . "</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Please Murphy how would you automatically copy and paste the book1.pdf into the <tr class='filesize'><?php echo filesize("../_____"); ?> bytes</tr>, since there are so many of them?

Comment: I updated the code but you need to show me some of the php / mysql you are doing

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to do, is to store all information in database. (if it's not already)
You can get all this file with file_get_contents(), put in a variable and use preg_match_all with a Regex Expression to return an array with the data, then use a loop to insert everything in db.